# what status code to be issued to google bot

Tags: googlebot

google is trying out different urls structures for my site and trying to crawl. I'm able to see these in my webmasters tool under crawl errors. What status code to be issued to all these request types from google bot.

Currently im issuing a 404 not found to all these pages. Is this safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 404 for URLs that have never existed, or pages that you purposely removed and don't want to redirect.

410s are also safe and processed in the same way. I've always used 404s for URLs that never existed and 410s for URLs that were there but are no longer available.

For the most part Googlebot will respect all valid status codes as long as you're using them appropriately.

Use a 503 if you ever have to take a site down for maintenance or if the service is unavailable. Use a 301 if you're redirecting old content to a new URL. It's a best practice to avoid using 302 redirects since they won't give you any SEO value ... and there are very rare cases when it should be used.

Lastly, never serve a 200 OK for an error page. Google may detect these from time to time and tell you that they've detected "Soft" 404s, and that they should be corrected.